# Postgres SQL Join on Nearest less than quarter end

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table 1

```
ID | public_date
1  | 1992-06-03
2  | 2000-12-15
```

Table 2 is a series of the quarter end dates in a range

```
Date
1995-12-31
1996-03-31
..
..
2000-12-31
```

I would like to have the result table as

```
ID | date        | public_date
1  | 1995-12-31  | 1992-06-03
1  | 1996-03-31  | 1992-06-03
1  | 1996-06-30  | 1992-06-03
      ...
      ...
1  | 2000-12-31  | 2000-12-15
```

Basically, assign the public date to the nearest quarter end date. Currently, I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (x."date")
       x."date", r.public_date
FROM   quarter_end_series as x
LEFT   JOIN public_time r ON r.public_date <= x."date" 
where x.date >= '1995-12-31 00:00:00'
ORDER  BY x."date", r.outlookdate desc;
```

But this query took 4 hours, any way to do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Try a subquery:

```
select pt.*,
       (select qes.date
        from quarter_end_series qes
        where qes.date <= pt.date
        order by qes.date desc
       ) as quarter_end_date
from public_time pt;
```

Include an index on `quarter_end_series(date)`.

This saves the sorting on a large amount of data -- which should make this more performant.

Comment: This query won't generate every quarter end dates between 2 public_dates

Comment: @Thien . . . I don't understand your comment.  This will return the quarter as described by your question for every row in `public_time`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your quarters are fixed for each year. Like:

```
1995-12-31
1996-03-31
1996-06-30
1996-09-31
1996-12-31
.... and so on
```

If it is then just find closest date from fixed quarter dates.

If `quarter_end_series` is not same dates for each year. You can try subquery instead of join. Like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("date")
"date", (SELECT r.public_date FROM public_time r ORDER BY abs(date_diff(x."date",r.public_date)) ASC limit 1) as public_date
FROM   quarter_end_series as x
where x.date >= '1995-12-31 00:00:00'
ORDER  BY x."date";
```

Comment: I am using Postgresql and the quarter dates is fixed for each year. My problem is the query took so long for million of rows